# Resolve a custom mimetype with apache Tika

Tags: mime-types, apache-tika

I have a .xml file with content like

```
<cesDoc version="v1" type="text" TEIform="TEI.2">
   <cesHeader type="text" version="v1" TEIform="teiHeader">
     ...
   </cesHeader>
   <text>
      <body>
         <div type="chapter">
            .... 
         </div>
      </body>
   </text>
</cesDoc>
```

which i want to identify as **"application/x-xces+xml"**

However tika (using version 2.8.0) detects it as "application/xml".

I have added the custom mime type as

```
<mime-type type="application/x-xces+xml">
    <sub-class-of type="application/xml"/>
    <magic priority="50">
        <match value="&lt;cesDoc" type="string" offset="0"/>
    </magic>
    <root-XML localName="cesDoc"/>
    <glob pattern="*.xml"/>
</mime-type>
```

How can I get Tika to make the correct identification, without having to rename the files, say, with a .xces extension (which then would be straightworward).

I have also increased magic priority but no effect.

Comment: It seems that if the input file does not have an XML declaration, the detection defaults to "application/xml". I don't know how to overcome this, since I have no control over the input files I want to detect.

Comment: Are you sure that your custom mime-type file is getting loaded by Tika?

Comment: Pretty sure. When I added xml declaration in a sample file it identified it as expected.

Comment: Can you view your file in a hex editor / hex viewer? I'm wondering if you've got byte order marks or similar before the initial tag which is preventing the string match

Comment: I figured it out. Some files have a <!DOCTYPE declaration at the top, so the offset="0" would not work. So I changed it to offset="0:80" and it worked even without XML declaration.

<magic priority="100">
            <match value="&lt;cesDoc" type="string" offset="0:80"/>
</magic>

Comment: You could have two magics, one which looks for the tag at 0, one which looks for doctype at 0 and your tag eg 10:80, that will be safer from false-positives

Comment: I'm intrigued to have "five magics", as a tribute to Megadeth, just for the sake of it :P!! Thanks for your help

Comment: See https://github.com/apache/tika/blob/a1b79e4727fd915775c9900c7d020c036affc89d/tika-core/src/main/resources/org/apache/tika/mime/tika-mimetypes.xml#L7449 for an example of multiple mime magics, some direct, some nested